# Finding order of the poles and its residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm a bit weak at this part, and was wondering if my approach is correct.
$$f(z) =\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin ^2 z}$$

Since $\lim_{z\rightarrow k\pi} f(z) = \infty$ for $k\neq 0$ or $1$, then $f$ has a pole at $z=k\pi$. Also, this pole is of order $2$ (just by looking at the multiplicity of $\sin ^2 z$). Is this the correct way of finding the order of a pole (inspecting multiplicities)?

So now I know that the residue at $z=k\pi$ will be
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow k\pi}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin ^2 z} \cdot (z-k\pi)\right).$$

Is there an easier way to find this residue? The derivative will be a bit tedious.

Comment: Where does that formula for computing residues come from? Do you believe that the residue at $0$ of $\frac1z$ is $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{-1}{z^2}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was using the formula that if $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$, then $$\text{Res}(f,z_0) = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} (z-z_0)^{m}f(z)$$

Comment: Oh I see, I forgot to put in the product $(z-k\pi)$ in the OP. I still find the same issue with it being a not-very-nice function to differentiate and take the limit, and wonder if there's an easier way to find the residue.

Comment: Right! You forgot that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue of $f$ at $0$ can be computed as follows: since $\frac z{\sin z}$ behaves as $1$ near $0$, you can forget it. What remains is $\frac{z-\pi}{\sin z}$, which has a single pole at $0$. The residue is then$$\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{z-\pi}{\sin z}=0-\pi=-\pi.$$

At $\pm\pi$ the situation is simpler, because $\pm\pi$ is a removable singularity of $f$:$$\lim_{z\to\pm\pi}\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin^2z}=\pm\pi\times(\pm1)^2=\pm\pi.$$Therefore, the residue is $0$.

---

The residue at $k\pi$, when $|k|>1$, can be computed without the formula that you mentioned. I shall do it when $k=2$. Note that$$z(z-\pi)^2=2 \pi ^3+5 \pi ^2 (z-2 \pi )+4 \pi  (z-2 \pi )^2+(z-2 \pi )^3$$and that\begin{align}\sin^2(z)&=\sin^2(z-2\pi)\\&=\frac12\bigl(1-\cos\bigl(2(z-2\pi)\bigr)\bigr)\\&=(z-2\pi)^2-\frac13(z-2\pi)^4+\cdots\end{align}Therefore, the Laurent series $\frac{z(\pi-z)^2}{\sin^2z}$ around $2\pi$ has the form$$\frac{a_{-2}}{(z-2\pi)^2}+\frac{a_{-1}}{z-2\pi}+a_0+a_1(z-2\pi)+a_2(z-2\pi)^2+\cdots$$with $a_{-2}=2\pi^3$. So\begin{multline}2 \pi ^3+5 \pi ^2 (z-2 \pi )+\cdots=\\=\left(\frac{2\pi^3}{(z-2\pi)^2}+\frac{a_{-1}}{z-2\pi}+a_0+\cdots\right)\left((z-2\pi)^2-\frac13(z-2\pi)^4+\cdots\right)\end{multline}and you can deduce from this equality that $$\operatorname{Res}_{2\pi}\left(\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin^2(z)}\right)=5\pi^2.$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there no simpler way to find the residues when $k\neq 0$ and $k\neq 1$?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours I've edited my answer. If the method that I provided is simpler, that's a matter of taste.