# Find the Residues of $f(z)=\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin^2(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus, laurent-series

> I am trying to find the residues of the function, $$f(z)=\frac{z(z-\pi)^2}{\sin^2(z)}.$$

My attempt:

I have considered three singularities: $z_0=0,\pi,k\pi \ (k\in\mathbb{Z}, \ k\neq 0,1).$

For $z_0=0$, I've determined this is a simple pole with Res$(f,0)=\pi^2$.

For $z_0=\pi$, I've determined this is a removable singularity and hence Res$(f,\pi)=0.$

For $z_o=k\pi$, I've determined this is a pole of order $2$, but cannot determine it's residue. I know it is possible using the formula, 
$$\text{Res}(f,k\pi)=\lim_{z\to k\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{z(z-k\pi)^2(z-\pi)^2}{\sin^2(z)}\right),$$ but I would like to use a more simpler approach through a series (but I am not sure of how to do so). I know I need to compute a Laurent series, but for this type of function, I am unsure.

Some advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Write $\sin^2 z=\sin^2(z-k\pi)$

Comment: And that $\sin^2u=u^2+O(u^4)$ when $u\to0$.

Comment: @Nosrati I do not see what this would achieve. Normally for computing a Laurent series, I would manipulate the function (depending on it's radius of convergence) to be in the form of a geometric series, $$\frac{1}{1-r}=\sum_{n\geq 0} r^k, \ \ |r|<1.$$ I don't see how to do that here.

Comment: @Did I do not see why this is without an explanation. Why would we take $u\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Because if $z\to k\pi$ and $z=u+k\pi$ then $u\to$ $___$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding order of the poles and its residue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441631/finding-order-of-the-poles-and-its-residue)